# Change colors and animate whenever user scrolls to another section using fullpage js

Tags: jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I am using the fullPage js plugin on my web page. I've added an animation to the first two sections, when the user scrolls to the other section, the color transitions gradually to the actual color of that section, and happens vice versa for the other section. You can see the animation here: https://rimildeyjsr.github.io/spotify-circle-animation/

The animation works properly only once, after the first time it doesn't work. I am using `onLeave` call to fire the script when I leave the section and `onLoad` to do fire the animation for the first time when changing to the section 2. I need the animation and color transistion to happen every time I leave the site.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

HTML

```
<div id="fullpage" style="-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">

        <div class="section" id="section1">
            <div class="button_container" id="toggle">
                <span class="top"></span>
                <span class="middle"></span>
                <span class="bottom"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="overlay" id="overlay">
                <nav class="overlay-menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li ><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="main-heading">
                <span id="main-heading"></span>
            </div>
            <span id="welcome-msg" class="come-in">Welcome to my website</span>
        </div>

        <div class="section" id="section2">
            <h1>I'm Prateek</h1>
            <h3>Independent Android Developer <br> & Design Consultant</h3>
            <p>I have been working on Android since the past<br> 3 years.
                I am a tech enthusiast and I like solving<br> problems which affect people’s lives, using<br>
                my skills. In my free time I blog about my,<br> learnings or design beautiful things.<br>
                Scroll along to check out my work. </p>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.colors {
    animation: color-animation 2s linear alternate;
}

@keyframes color-animation {
    0% {
        background: rgb(35,204,223);
    }
    10%{
        background: rgb(35,187,209);
    }
    20%{
        background: rgb(34,170,196);
    }
    30%{
        background: rgb(34,153,182);
    }
    40%{
        background: rgb(33,136,168);
    }
    50%{
        background: rgb(33,118,155);
    }
    60%{
        background: rgb(32,101,141);
    }
    70%{
        background: rgb(32,84,127);
    }
    80%{
        background: rgb(31,67,114);
    }
    100%{
        background: rgb(31,50,100);
    }

}

.colors-reverse {
    animation: colors-reverse-animation 2s linear alternate;
}

@keyframes colors-reverse-animation {
    0% {
        background: rgb(31,50,100);
    }
    10%{
        background: rgb(31,67,114);
    }
    20%{
        background: rgb(32,84,127);
    }
    30%{
        background: rgb(32,101,141);
    }
    40%{
        background: rgb(33,118,155);
    }
    50%{
        background: rgb(33,136,168);
    }
    60%{
        background: rgb(34,153,182);
    }
    70%{
        background: rgb(34,170,196);
    }
    80%{
        background: rgb(35,187,209);
    }
    100%{
        background: rgb(35,204,223);
    }
}
```

JQuery:

```
(document).ready(function(){
            $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                anchors: ['home','about','projects','blog','contact'],
                fixedElements: '#toggle,#overlay',
                afterLoad : function(anchorLink,index) {
                    if(index == 1 || anchorLink == 'home'){

                    }
                     else if(index == 2 || anchorLink == 'about'){
                        $('#section2').addClass('colors').one(animationEnd,function () {
                            $('#section2').css('background','#1f3264');
                        });
                        $('#section2 h1').addClass('come-in').one(animationEnd,function(){
                            $('#section2 h3').addClass('come-in').one(animationEnd,function(){
                                $('#section2 p').addClass('come-in');
                            });
                        });
                    }
                    else if (index == 5 || anchorLink == 'contact') {
                         $('.left').addClass('animateRightSlide');
                         $('.right-large').addClass('animateLeftSlide');
                    }
                },
                onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {
                    if (index == 1 && direction == 'down') {
                        $('#section2').addClass('colors').one(animationEnd,function () {
                            $('#section2').css('background','#1f3264');
                        });
                    }
                    else if (index == 2 && direction == 'up') {
                        $('#section1').addClass('colors-reverse').one(animationEnd,function () {
                            $('#section1').css('background','#24ccdf');
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem after a long time - I hadn't been removing the class. So by adding removeClass() after the animation is done, the problem is solved.

jQuery

```
var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                anchors: ['home','about','projects','blog','contact'],
                fixedElements: '#toggle,#overlay',
                afterLoad : function(anchorLink,index) {
                    if(index == 1 || anchorLink == 'home'){

                    }
                     else if(index == 2 || anchorLink == 'about'){
                        $('#section2').addClass('colors').one(animationEnd,function () {
                            $('#section2').removeClass('colors');
                            $('#section2').css('background','#1f3264');
                        });
                        $('#section2 h1').addClass('come-in').one(animationEnd,function(){
                            $('#section2 h3').addClass('come-in').one(animationEnd,function(){
                                $('#section2 p').addClass('come-in');
                            });
                        });
                    }
                    else if (index == 5 || anchorLink == 'contact') {
                         $('.left').addClass('animateRightSlide');
                         $('.right-large').addClass('animateLeftSlide');
                    }
                },
                onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {
                    if (index == 1 && direction == 'down') {
                        $('#section2').addClass('colors').one(animationEnd,function () {
                            $('#section2').removeClass('colors');
                            $('#section2').css('background','#1f3264');
                        });
                    }
                    else if (index == 2 && direction == 'up') {
                        $('#section1').addClass('colors-reverse').one(animationEnd,function () {
                            $('#section1').removeClass('colors-reverse');
                            $('#section1').css('background','#24ccdf');
                        });
                    }
                    else if (index == 3 && direction == 'up') {
                        $('#section2').addClass('colors').one(animationEnd,function () {
                            $('#section2').removeClass('colors');
                            $('#section2').css('background','#1f3264');
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
});
```